# Is there a risk to leaving my headset always on?

Tags: damage

I use my computer 10h a day, and am usually listening to music by having it connected to my amp. However I also have a headset (AKG k271 MKII), and I have a habit of leaving it plugged in, just in case I want to use it.

Does doing this damage it in any way? Shortens its lifespan?

Comment: Ever been in an elevator?… muzak 24/7/365 Speakers last for decades, if not over-pushed.

Comment: That makes sense! I guess I'm worried about it loosing quality/fidelity over time? But I know little about audio so I'm not sure that's a real issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no danger posed to your headset by leaving it plugged in for long periods. The lifespan will not be shortened by any perceivable amount.